# Overwrite a table in CartoDB

Tags: carto

I need to overwrite a table in CartoDB using the Import API, but the system instead of overwriting the table, it creates another one with the same name and attaches an id auto-generated.

For instance:

The table stored in CartoDB is named **coordinates**.

When I overwrite the table, it creates a table named **coordinates_1** for instance.

Is it possible to overwrite the same table with different data?

Comment: that's a good point. I am also interested on knowing if given a table we can have some real time update service to that table so the map is constantly being updated. That would be a great feature to have. hope someone answers.

Comment: There's several real time update capabilities. You can use sync tables http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/realtime_maps_sync.html to automatically keep up to date online. You can also use the SQL API to update your tables directly. See http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html#write-data-to-your-cartodb-account

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an example commandline tool in python that does something like this. [Blog post](http://blog.cartodb.com/access-cartodb-from-any-language-an-example-in-python/) and [code](https://gist.github.com/andrewxhill/093c89fa45e5f657fec7)

The important piece is here, https://gist.github.com/andrewxhill/093c89fa45e5f657fec7#file-cartodb-utils-py-L76

You can see that the biggest limitation is that, since it does a naive DELETE followed by INSERT, if the columns of your tables differ, it will fail. You could make it a bit smarter by detecting column differences and doing an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN before the INSERT step.

Answer (score 0):

In CartoDB many tables are linked to maps and cannot be overwritten directly. You need to use CartoDB PostGIS SQL to truncate your table first like this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE my_layer
```

Then use ogr2ogr version 2.0 or greater to append new data to the truncated table using a command something like this:

```
ogr2ogr -append --config CARTODB_API_KEY abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f CartoDB "CartoDB:username" my_layer.shp
```

A detailed explanation is presented here:
[Data Synchronization with OGR](http://blog.cartodb.com/data-sync-ogr/)

It isn't mentioned in the explanation above, but I use the same method to update non spatial tables with CSV files. Just use my_layer.csv to end of the ogr2ogr command instead of my_layer.shp.