# Import data from a csv file to existing table cartodb

Tags: carto

I am trying to add data to an existing CartoDB table from a local csv file. Using Import API creates a new table. How can I specify to add data to existing table instead of new table?

Comment: Please see: [Overwrite a table in CartoDB](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113969/overwrite-a-table-in-cartodb/190540#190540)

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that standard tables in CartoDB allow appending rows to existing tables.  If you look at the [**API**](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/import-api.html#standard-tables) there is an append parameter but it says that it is "Reserved for future usage.".

However, I did find **[this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cartodb/ddg1kkyoszE/zIePrz9fSqwJ)** which indicates that you can import using SQL, provided the schemas match.

Like so:

```
INSERT INTO mastertable SELECT * FROM anewtable
```